# Easy way styling select box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, select

Is there any easy way to add a style to a select box in a `form` using jQuery?

```
<select>
  <option>sample</option>
  <option>sample1</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't style select boxes, try reading up on `progressive enhancement` ..

Comment: We can style `select` Read http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/  Another stackoverflow Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/). It will style a select box and can also use Ajax to get data on the fly.

```
$(selector).select2();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can alternatively use [jQuery.SimpleSelect](http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect), which is nothing less than a very simple and lightweight (1.75kb gzipped) plugin that will transform your `<select>` elements into a bunch of divs you'll be able to style however you want using CSS.

It's as simple as that:

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("select").simpleselect();
```

And (with default styles that you can obviously customize), it gives you this:

[image]

[**Documentation**](http://pioul.fr/jquery-simpleselect)

Answer (score 2):

Try easy styling select box using jquery

```
  <select class="selectboxdiv">

      <option>choose preset...</option>
      <option>two</option>
      <option>something</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>

  </select>

  <div class="out"></div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9Wt89/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the `<select>` node but you can visually represent styled `<ul>` node that it is a dropdown menu. Just When the page loads hide the original dropdown menu and create one by forming a list by `<ul>` tag. And when the user click on `<li>` node then change also the value of `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *easy way* to style form elements in general to be consistent across browsers. But you could go for plugins like [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style the `<select>` tag. Trying wrapping them around with some HTML and you can style/script your HTMLs as you need.

You can do something like this (in jQuery), wrap your `<select>` with some markup,

```
<div class="selectBox">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then map `<li>` changes to `<option>` changes in your script.