# Simple Custom Select Box with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found this really great solution for a simple custom select box - it works beautifully however it only works for one select box. I've been tinkering with it for the past 2 or 3 hours and I can't for life of me figuring it out so that it works for all custom selects.

The issue is this line of code is very specific - I need it to output text that should be unique to the select box that it's being applied to

```
 $(".out").text(str);
```

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
$('select[name=Listing_Price_Max]').change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    $(".out").text(str);
}).trigger('change');
```

Credit to Sanddip for his helpful solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/16145673/1108360 - I just need to get a little more out of it. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes with this and a jsFiddle.net example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to do it this way:

```
 $(this).next(".out").text(str); //Select the div that is next to the selectBox
```

provided your structure is like this:

```
<div class="selectdiv">
    <select class="selectboxdiv">
        <option>choose preset...</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>something</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
    <div class="out">XCZXCzxcxz</div>
</div>
```

#### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9BHLD/)

See [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: you beated me for 1 minute :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom selectbox using jquery. You can do this without using any third party large sized plugin.

You can theme it using small css code.

I found this [link](http://www.codeinsects.com/stylize-your-select-box-using-jquery-custom-plugin.html) very useful to create custom select box using jquery

http://www.codeinsects.com/stylize-your-select-box-using-jquery-custom-plugin.html